# Can skill checks for theft and/or trespassing scale beyond 100?

Tags: the-outer-worlds

If a player gets caught trespassing using the disguise module, or if they get caught stealing something, they can try a skill check that gets harder every time the player gets caught. Can this skill check eventually require a skill of over 100 for successful completion? Because you can get to 100 skill at level 8 or so if you rush it, and it feels like that might break such checks if they're capped at 100.

Answer (score 2):

I've beat Outer Worlds and never saw a skill check require more than 100 in a given skill. There are a handful of end-game skill checks that actually hit 100, but none that I've seen go beyond.

Comment: It seems that DLC (currently only Peril on Gorgon) increases that to 150, since there are plenty of hacking/lockpicking checks at 150 there.